# Making a sequence of Unicode characters non-editable

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf, unicode-string

Is there a possibility to combine a couple of Unicode characters so that when gets inserted into text editor it would behave like a single entity? Pretty much like emoji, i.e. (3 characters combined into one). Ideally if the output behaved like a single character, although from what I learned the only option here is a custom font that would provide such symbols and this is not possible in my case.

For a better context:
I make a plugin for GDocs. I need a special set of numeral symbols - all permutations of 2-3 digits (1, 43, 623 etc.). Up to 3 digits would perfect but 2 are quite ok too. I can't allow user to "break" a sequence, i.e. insert a char in-between digits, or erase one ("12m4" - bad).

The special font would solve my problem - there even is one that looks good, but in GDocs I cannot introduce custom font.

Is there some way to do it? Maybe with the hacky use of non-spacing characters between chars, or maybe some other symbols that could help here but I'm not aware of it?

Comment: this looks like something close... when you try to select it, it gets selected as a whole rather than chars one by one https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+01F1

Comment: and here is pretty much what i'm trying to achieve. is is possible to make custom similar "boxed" symbols with multiple chars inside? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/General_Punctuation#/endnoteU2000asofUnicodeversion